# Why does DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_CACHE phase come before DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE?

Tags: caching, bootstrapping

According to this [article](http://mikecr.it/ramblings/how-drupal-7-works-part-2-the-bootstrap) about `drupal_bootstrap` function, all parameters for drupal_bootstrap() run sequentially. And if we see the sequence, here first comes - `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIGURATION`, second `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_CACHE` and then database (`DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE`),

So, My question is cache is itself stored in database, so in order to serve pages from cache, a database connection is a must. Then How Drupal manages these calls sequentially?

Accordingly, `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE` should come before `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_CACHE`. If not, what is the reason?

Comment: I don't know the reason, but I do know that (at least in D8) you can set a cache system that doesn't rely on a db connection.

Comment: The caching backend may not be the local database. It could be external, like memcache.

Comment: Don't agree with the close votes on this.  Rationale behind core implementation is perfectly acceptable, and can be answered definitively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of [_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7.x) the key bit of information is this bit of code

```
  if (variable_get('page_cache_without_database')) {
    $cache_enabled = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_VARIABLES, FALSE);
    $cache_enabled = variable_get('cache');
  }
```

The call to bootstrap DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_VARIABLES will also bootstrap DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE because it's before variables inside of [drupal_bootstrap()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7.x)

What this means is if your cache doesn't require a database connection (like [memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) or [filecache](https://www.drupal.org/project/filecache)) then you can speedup page cache hits by not connecting to the database. The linked article talks about this.